# Table rows show/hide - remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is, why I can not use `hide()` & `show()` to hide/show table rows on my web page. Browser freezes if I use any of those, but if I use `remove()` it works fine, but then I cannot get this row back(or?).

If I use show and hide on any other thing's it work's just fine. What did I do wrong?

```
    for(var i=0; i<=pages-begin; i=i+1){
       if($("#myTable2 tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child("+ rowIndex +")").text() == $(this).text()){
       $("#myTable2 tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child("+ rowIndex +")").parent().remove(); i=i-1;}
    }
```

EDIT:

I used `live()`, and as I read just now toggle and such do not work inside `live()`... but I still need answer :(

```
$("#dropMenuFilter ul li").live("click", function(){
for(var i=0; i<=strani-zacetek; i=i+1){
    if($("#myTable2 tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child("+ rowIndex +")").text() == $(this).text()){
    $("#myTable2 tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child("+ rowIndex +")").parent().fadeOut(); i=i-1;}
}});
```

dropMenuFilter is some div, on which I append `.text()` of specific `<td>` and I wish, that when I click on it, it will remove parent of this td: table row. It works with `remove()`...

Comment: what actually do you want . please ad the html and explain the question

Comment: put you test code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link

Comment: Can't reproduce your bug: http://jsfiddle.net/rByTm/ (works in FF11 and IE9).

Comment: ok guys, i made it =)
it was easy :| i have to use another function an in this function just use toggle(). thanks anyway

Comment: Post your soloution and close the thread, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soloution:

```
function removeRow(vrstica){
    $("#myTable2 tr:nth-child("+vrstica+") td:nth-child("+ rowIndex +")").parent().toggle();
}

$("#dropMenuFilter ul li").live("click", function(){
    for(var i=1; i<=strani-zacetek; i+=1){
        if($("#myTable2 tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child("+ rowIndex +")").text() == $(this).text()){
            removeRow(i);
        }
    }
})
```